# Global Array in TCL

Tags: tcl

I want to know how to make or create a global Array in *TCL*, to access it inside the `Procedure`. I mean, If I have a `Procedure` and I want to get the Array values to use it inside the Procedure, how can I do that?

Comment: You might benefit from reading the [Tcl tutorial](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) -- variable scope is covered in chapter 16.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`global`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm) to access the array. E.g.

```
array set myArr {a 1 b 2 c 3}

proc foo {} {
    global myArr
    parray myArr
}

foo
#=> myArr(a) = 1
#=> myArr(b) = 2
#=> myArr(c) = 3
```

Using access the global [`namespace`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm) using `::`:

```
proc bar {} {
    parray ::myArr
}
#=> ::myArr(a) = 1
#=> ::myArr(b) = 2
#=> ::myArr(c) = 3
```

You can also use [`upvar`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm) and [`uplevel`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/uplevel.htm), they might or might not be easier to understand depending on your experience with Tcl; they require you to understand levels (or stack frames). Basically, the global namespace is at level 0, or #0, and each time you go into a `proc`, you go deeper by 1 level.

Comment: Thanks, sir for your answer...I define it as a global...and define it...it works.